# Salesforce MFA in simple-salesforce

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am currently using the `simple-salesforce` library to retrieve data from Salesforce, using the token method.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username='myemail@example.com', password='password', security_token='token')
```

But Salesforce is requiring the implementation of a Multi-Factor Authentication, is there anyway I can bypass this or use another method?

Here is the link of the actual article:
`https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000356005&type=1&mode=1`

Thanks!

Comment: If MFA would be able to be bypassed, it wouldn't be worth much, would it?

Comment: @AKX you're right, that's why I'm asking if there is an alternative method.

Comment: Well, you're not the only one asking. https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution:

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/457

In my case, I was not using an API user account, rather just a normal user account.

Answer (score 1):

I think MFA will be required only for users using the standard login - from the Help article [mentioned above](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000356005&type=1&mode=1), it says:
"All internal users who log in to Salesforce products* (including partner solutions) **through the user interface** must use MFA. To ensure that MFA is enabled for all your Salesforce users, you can turn it on directly in your Salesforce products or use your SSO provider's MFA service."

But you are auth'ing via the API, right?

Can you share an error message or screenshot?

Typically API auths happen via a connected app configured in the org, and as I recall, the connected app has a setting requiring MFA ...
[This help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1) goes into greater detail about where MFA is required (which login approaches)

Could it be that you are running into the standard user verification challenge whenever salesforce sees an auth for a user from a new network location. You can disable that [here](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000prDQQAY) by setting an IP address range.

Comment: I'm currently not authing through the api, just a normal account with api permissions.  I will need to create an API account and probably use the JWT method of accessing the data when MFA is mandatory.